# create and set new user and password to the imported schema in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have imported a sql dump from a server to my local database.

As for now, root can automatically can access my new schema.

How can I create and set a username and password to that particular schema (eg.myDB1), so I can make sure all things are same from the local and server.

Edited: I want to set up e.g., kito as username and 123 as password.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: google "mysql grant" and "mysql create user"

Comment: And when you got it, it would be nice to post your answer here and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Create a particular user,

```
shell> mysql --user=root mysql

mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
```

Then grant access to that user to a particular database,

```
mysql> grant usage on *.* to monty@localhost identified by 'some_pass';

mysql> grant all privileges on amarokdb.* to monty@localhost ;
```

Ref:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-create-a-mysql-database-and-set-privileges-to-a-user